# NextJs and MUI datepicker Error `readOnly` did not match. Server: "" Client: "false"

Tags: next.js, material-ui

Warning: Prop `readOnly` did not match. Server: "" Client: "false"
Iv tried to use Mobile and Dekstop

```
const isDesktop = useMediaQuery('(min-width:900px)');
```

And then i render Desktop or Mobile date picker depends of this value. But anyway getting error. Any suggestions how i can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I added workaround but looks ugly as for me.

```
const [isDesktop, setIsDesktop] = useState(true);    
const theme = useTheme();
const match = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'));

 useEffect(() => {
    setIsDesktop(match);
  }, [match]);

 and then condition which datepicker i want render.
```